# org-mode code block for an unknown language?

Tags: org-mode

I want to display a block of code in a documentation file as, well ..., a block of code.
In markdown language, this can be achieved by quoting the code using a pair of backticks "`".

*Can this be safely done in org-mode?*

The language is not on the org-babel supported list:
https://orgmode.org/manual/Languages.html#Languages
, so I am not sure what to use for the required  field of `#+begin_src`.

By the way, I do not intend to execute the code in the .org file.

Comment: If there is a major mode for that language in emacs, use the name of the major mode (without the `-mode` suffix): you'll get formatting and fontification even if you cannot execute the code.